# Javascript inside 'script' tag versus 'application.js'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

What is the difference between using javascript inside the `<script>` tag in the view and using `application.js` file?

I need to pass variables directly in javascript like this:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>

//OTHER CODE etc etc...

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
  $('#myDiv_<%= post.id %>').scroll(function() {
    var url;
    url = $('.myClass_<%= post.id %> .next_page').attr('href');
    if (url && $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) {
      $('.myClass_<%= post.id %>').text('Fetching more posts...');
      return $.getScript(url);
    }
  });
  return $(window).scroll();
});
</script>

<% end %>
```

I put my `<script>` inside a each iterator, so I have access to single a variable with unique id to set id and classes.

Is it safe to use this code inside the view in a each iterator? Is it secure using `getScript(Url)` like this? Is there another way to pass these variables post to my `application.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally don't want to do this. What you have here is Ruby inside ERB inside JavaScript inside HTML inside a template, and that's simply way too many layers.

It's must better to try and express this as a `data` property on some field, and then your `application.js` can make use of those variables later on. This saves dumping out multiple lines of JavaScript that are 95% the same each time you render the page.

For example:

```
var $postId = $('#lastDiv').data('postId');
```

Where you can have `data-postId='...'` within your HTML somewhere. That means your JavaScript doesn't change, it just adapts to use whatever's on the page itself.